# How to select concave quads

Tags: selection-tools, topology

how can i select all concave quads, is there such a tool?
[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is going to get you the selection that you need, but if you select one face and then press SHIFT + G you will see a menu called "Select Similar" try with one option and see if that works for you

Comment: @Emir nah, none of those work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be a naive answer, I'm no coder, but is there anything wrong with letting [`BMLoop.is_convex`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLoop.is_convex) do this for you?

(Starting from Edit Mode):

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bm.faces.active = None

for face in bm.faces:
    face.select_set(False)
    for loop in face.loops:
        if not loop.is_convex:
            face.select_set(True)
            break

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, False)
```

Comment: Looks good to me.  Could use `face.select_set(not any(loop.is_convex for loop in face.loops))`  as I'm led to believe it is quicker, although can't see it being any more than an bee's diaphragm.

Comment: @batFINGER there ya go! I  _knew_ there would be a snappier way of putting it! I'll just leave it in your comment.

Comment: Good find, will make that edge angle answer easier too,  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203249/face-edges-angle-python  in that can simply use `edge.angle(otheredge)`  and add pi if not convex.  Consider adding as answer there too.  Gives me that _",,,Whale oil beef hooked how did I miss thaaaaat"_ feeling.

Comment: @batFINGER wilco, when I have some time to grind through my incredibly slow beginner's testing-and-looking-stuff-up, unless you go in first. I can't remember when I spotted that property.. it was in a completely different context.

Comment: cool, this is kind of odd to me that although there is a parameter that straightly tells you, that the face is convex , there is no just button in GUI for common users

Comment: @Timur Agreed. It would seem a very obvious 'By Trait', or 'Clean Up'.

Answer (score 4):

ok, so I made a modification of this script: [Face edges angle - python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203249/face-edges-angle-python)

I simply putted some selection commands at the end.
it will do the work (you need to select the faces you want to check)

```
# based on the script by batFINGER: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203249/face-edges-angle-python
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from bpy import context
from math import degrees, atan2, pi
import bmesh
# project into XY plane, 
up = Vector((0, 0, 1))

ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
def edge_angle(e1, e2, face_normal):
    b = set(e1.verts).intersection(e2.verts).pop()
    a = e1.other_vert(b).co - b.co
    c = e2.other_vert(b).co - b.co
    a.negate()    
    axis = a.cross(c).normalized()
    if axis.length < 1e-5:
        return pi # inline vert
    
    if axis.dot(face_normal) < 0:
        axis.negate()
    M = axis.rotation_difference(up).to_matrix().to_4x4()  

    a = (M @ a).xy.normalized()
    c = (M @ c).xy.normalized()
    
    return pi - atan2(a.cross(c), a.dot(c))

selected_faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
for f in selected_faces:
    edges = f.edges[:]
    #print("Face", f.index, "Edges:", [e.index for e in edges])
    edges.append(f.edges[0])
    
    for e1, e2 in zip(edges, edges[1:]):

        angle = edge_angle(e1, e2, f.normal)
        
        #print("Edge Corner", e1.index, e2.index, "Angle:", degrees(angle))
        if degrees(angle) >= 180:
            f.select_set(True)
```

Comment: Could possibly do something like `f.select_set(any(edge_angle(e1, e2, f.normal) > pi for e1, e2 in zip(edges, edges[1:]))`

Comment: @batFINGER thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I see I'm late, though I ended up with simpler code:

```
import bpy

tolerance = 0  # increase to something like .01 or .1 to ignore small concavities

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="FACE")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

me = bpy.context.active_object.data
me.calc_loop_triangles()
poly_i_to_tris = {}
for tri in me.loop_triangles:
    poly_i_to_tris.setdefault(tri.polygon_index, []).append(tri)

for i, tris in poly_i_to_tris.items():
    try:
        t1, t2 = tris
    except ValueError:
        continue  # not a quad
    dist = (t1.center - t2.center).length
    tolerance *= dist  # makes tolerance relative
    ray_len = dist/2  # making sure to not overshoot, but I don't think it would be possible
    test1 = t1.center + t1.normal*ray_len
    test2 = t2.center + t2.normal*ray_len
    test_dist = (test1 - test2).length
    if test_dist < dist - tolerance:
        # concave
        me.polygons[i].select = True
    
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you decide to remove `ray_len`, then use `dist` instead of not multiplying the normals - or otherwise you will lose the relativity of `tolerance`. 

Comment: Reading through the other answer's code, I now realize I misunderstood the question. What I thought of a concave quad, is a quad triangulated in such way, that the diagonal of the quad (the edge created by tessellation) falls down along the face normal. You can clearly see it in attached .blend file.

Comment: Wondered about that,  Would you say this is looking for non-coplanar  faces?

Comment: @batFINGER in short I'm checking if two segments starting at centers of triangles and going outside along normals, end up being closer than those centers. If so, those triangles look at each-other, and the quad is *"concave"*. If the opposite is the case, the triangles are upset at each-other, and the quad is *"convex"*. Otherwise the quad is *"flat"* or coplanar. (in my script I just select the *"concave"* because that was the question, but you could differentiate all three, and e.g. color the cube dynamically)

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102440/left-right-test

Comment: Also similarly to @RobinBetts answer above, looks like this test could be achieved very simply with `BMEdge.is_convex`.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks, I didn't know of `is_convex`. So the alternative to my solution would be to find which edge is added in tessellation and check if it's convex. Though this wouldn't allow for tolerance or 3-way split into convex/flat/concave, so I'll leave my answer as is. As for left-right-test, you overestimate my IQ.