# Moving a vertex makes only half of the connected faces move in the right way

Tags: modeling

Sorry if the title doesn't accurately describe my problem, I am new to Stack Exchange. I need to make all the faces move up equally, but the ones circled in yellow only move up half way, while the ones in red are how I want them to move. This has happened to me multiple times with different models and I am trying to find a solution
[image: What the problem is]

[image: What it should look like]

Comment: Hello :). The problem is called non-planar faces (if you want to read up on it). Triangles always stay planar, so they might work better in this case.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky/56764#56764

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem comes down to changing the internal triangulation done by Blender, as described by Robin Betts here: [flipping internal triangulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212462/)

In your particular case: select problematic faces, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate, change *Quad Method* to *Fixed Alternate*, select the new edges and dissolve them:

[image]

If you want to make a script automatically fixing such quads, this could be a starting point: [Select concave quads](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/222167/)

Comment: I thought of a similar situation, but I decided to tell about proportional editing since it would  be a less complicated way for begginers and did not deal with fixing improper meshes.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is proportional editing. Press 'O' or that little icon on the top highlighted in the image below. Then when you move a vertex you will see a circle around the vertex you have selected. The size of the circle is controlled by the scroll wheel on a mouse. The bigger the area the circle is, the more strongly the other vertices will move with that single vertex.[image: Blender screenshot of pulling a vertex on a sphere]

Comment: I disagree this is the best solution, I even doubt this is at all a solution the OP is interested in, however it could be helpful to other visitors finding this thread through google... 